# I want to save just value in react-select

Tags: reactjs, select, label

I have some trouble with my react-select: When I click 'Submit', it save an object that have both 'value' and 'label' like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODiqE.png)

All I need is when I choose, it's show label list, and when I submit, it save only value. What can I do? Here are my code:

```
const [mainLang, setMainLang] = useState("");
const mainLangOptions = [
    { value: 'vi', label: 'Vietnamese' },
    { value: 'en', label: 'English' },
    { value: 'zh', label: 'Chinese' },
    { value: 'ja', label: 'Japanese' },
    { value: 'de', label: 'German' },
];
//This is Select part
 <Select 
     onChange={(e) =>setMainLang(e)}
     options={mainLangOptions}
 />
```

Comment: are you using material ui select ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the option value as the mainLangOptions.value and the label as
mainLangOptions.label. By doing that you will display the label as option labels and save the value as the value of option tag. Check out the code below :

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      mainLanguage: ""
    };
  }
  onOptionChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.state.mainLanguage = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.state.mainLanguage);
  };
  render() {
    const mainLangOptions = [
      { value: "vi", label: "Vietnamese" },
      { value: "en", label: "English" },
      { value: "zh", label: "Chinese" },
      { value: "ja", label: "Japanese" },
      { value: "de", label: "German" }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onOptionChangeHandler}>
          <option>Please choose one option</option>
          {mainLangOptions.map((option, index) => {
            return (
              <option value={option.value} key={index}>
                {option.label}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: the question is about react-select library not select tag.

Answer (score -1):

You must use e.target.value inside your setMainLang

```
<Select onChange={(e) => setMainLang(e.target.value)}>
```

This should work for your code but if it doesn't work, here is a complete code that I have tested in code sandbox and you can try it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const Users = () => {
  const [mainLang, setMainLang] = useState("");
  const mainLangOptions = [
    { value: "vi", label: "Vietnamese" },
    { value: "en", label: "English" },
    { value: "zh", label: "Chinese" },
    { value: "ja", label: "Japanese" },
    { value: "de", label: "German" }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <Select onChange={(e) => setMainLang(e.target.value)}>
        {mainLangOptions.map((op) => (
          <option value={op.value}>{op.label}</option>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <h1>{mainLang}</h1>
    </>
  );
};
export default Users;
```

Comment: The Question is about react-select not @chakra-ui.

Comment: the question must have been edited, back then it was using chakra-ui